# PolymerとBootstrapの併用について

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, polymer, web-component

お世話になってます。
現在Bootstrapを使用してWebサイトを開発しています。
しかし、Polymerを利用して部品化してみようと思い、Polymerを導入したのですが、BootstrapのclassがComponentに反映されなかったりと何かと不具合が生じています。
Componentのhtmlには
polymer.htmlとbootstrap.min.cssをlinkしています。

具体的な不具合の例として
・header内に定義したComponentのh1などの文字が小さくなる。(fontが変更されている？)
・Bootstrapのclassが要素に反映されない。
　img-circle等が反映されない。Component化しなければ反映されるのでブラウザの問題
　ではなさそうです。
といった事が生じています。

BootstrapとPolymerは併用するべきではないのでしょうか？
Polymerのverは0.5.0
Bootstrapのverは3.3.4です。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
Web Componentsで生成するhtmlのコードです。

宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

コードが無いので推測ですが、それは不具合では無く ShadowDOM の仕様によるものだと考えられます。

ShadowDOM は CSS の境界を作ります。
ShadowDOM の外で定義された CSS ルールは、ShadowDOM の内部に影響を与えません。
ShadowDOM の中で定義された CSS ルールは、ShadowDOM の外部に影響を与えません。

つまり、Web Components の内部で使う CSS は、Web Components の内部に書かなければいけません。
そして、例えば `table { background: red; }` のようなルールを定義したとしても、それは Web Components の内部にしか影響を与えません (外にあるテーブルの色は変わりません)。

Comment: さっそくの回答ありがとうございます。
ShadowDOMの仕様ですか。全くの盲点でした。
まだまだ、勉強が足りないようです。
ShadowDOMの外で定義されたCSSのルールが適用されないため、
Web Componentsで新たに生成したhtmlの中ではBootstrapのCSSが効かないのだとの意味でしょうか？
もしそうでしたら、Web Componentで生成したhtmlに<link>でCSSをリンクしてもCSSの実態が外にあるからCSSのルールが適用されないのでしょうか？

Comment: はい。ShadowDOMの中に書かれたstyleタグであれば、そのShadowDOMの内部の要素に適用されます。linkタグによるスタイルの引用は、本来の仕様では適用されません。しかし、PolymerはShadowDOMの中にあるlinkタグを見つけると、ajaxでcssファイルを取得してstyleタグとして展開してくれます。そのため、Polymerを使っていれば、ShadowDOM内でlinkタグを書けば意図通りの結果になると思います。